# What is the meaning of `context` argument in `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

`context` is an optional argument in the constructor of `class multiprocessing.pool.Pool`. [Documentation](http://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) only says:

> `context` can be used to specify the context used for starting the worker processes. Usually a pool is created using the function `multiprocessing.Pool()` or the `Pool()` method of a context object. In both cases context is set appropriately.

It doesn't clarify what a "context object" is, why `class Pool` constructor needs it, and what it means that it "is set appropriately" in the mentioned scenarios.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depending on the platform, multiprocessing supports three ways to start a process. These start methods are:

- spawn:

  The parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process.
  Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows.
- fork:

  The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter.
  Available on Unix only. The default on Unix.
- forkserver

  When the program starts and selects the forkserver start method, a server   process is started. From then on, whenever a new process is needed, the parent process connects to the server and requests that it fork a new process. The fork server process is single threaded so it is safe for it to use os.fork(). No unnecessary resources are inherited.

  Available on Unix platforms which support passing file descriptors over Unix pipes.

---

To select a start method you use the set_start_method() in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause of the main module. For example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```

Alternatively, you can use get_context() to obtain a context object. Context objects have the same API as the multiprocessing module, and allow one to use multiple start methods in the same program.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    q = ctx.Queue()
    p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```

This is where the context object came from!

Comment: If only I didn't give up searching for the word `context` in that doc page after a couple unrelated matches about context managers :)

Comment: The context is actually incredibly helpful. For example on Unix the `multiprocessing.Pool` uses the `fork` start method to start processes by default. If you want it to use a different start method, simply create the context and then use the `ctx.Pool`.

Comment: what situation need i use `mp.get_context`?`mp.Pool` always work well @Jeyekomon

Comment: @UN2758 In the most simple situations you don't need to care about context, just ignore it (as you do now) and the default one will be used automatically. You care about it when you want to control inheritance of resources from the parent process.