# What is a context object in multiprocessing module and what is the use of it

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

So I saw the below code in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) of  multiprocessing module what does this get_context()
function do and why we are using ctx instead of mp ? I am not able to understand it

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    q = ctx.Queue()
    p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of \`context\` argument in \`multiprocessing.pool.Pool\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818519/what-is-the-meaning-of-context-argument-in-multiprocessing-pool-pool)

Comment: no actually he just wrote the definition from the doc, I am not able to understand it fully. though I understood the set_start_method but not get_context

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: like why we are using ctx instead of mp